# Camera in Service and onPreviewFrame

Tags: android

I have a Service that opens the front camera and shows its preview.
Now I want to do some image processing on the preview image, and so I set a preview callback.

My problem is that the callback is not called, and I get the infamous Choreographer message "skipped X frames... Too much work on its main thread"
This seems very weird, since all I currently do in the callback is print a log line.
Moreover, when I debug (via ADT), and I break on the log printing line, it is called (but not if I  let it run, then try to break it sometime on the line).
this happens when I run it on my tablet (I'm not using an emultor), but when I run it on my phone (Nexus 5, stronger than my tablet), the callback is called successfully each time, no frames skipped.

My custom surfaceholder surfaceCreated():

```
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    try {
        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Error setting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    try {
        mCamera.setPreviewCallback(new Camera.PreviewCallback() {

            public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera arg1) {
                   Log.d("Freshub.BackgroundService", "onPreviewFrame Called!!");
            }
        });
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    mCamera.startPreview();
}
```

Any suggestion as to how to get it to work on my tablet?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it in a `Service`.
The [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) states:

> A Service is an application component that can perform long-running operations in the background and **does not provide a user interface**.

You should do it inside an Activity.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but that is very wrong. A service does not provide a user interface, but it can definitely hold a View, as I do have a camera preview showing on a layout, and everything works fine on my phone.

Comment: If the view is not displayed, the System won't let you capture frames from the camera. BTW, holding a view outside an Activity context will certainly lead to memory leak ;)

Comment: The view is displayed, and on my phone everything works fine. Holding a view out of an activity context will not by itself cause a memory leak. Its actually quite a common practice. Take Facebook messenger for example (as seen here: [http://www.piwai.info/chatheads-basics/]